# Finding trajectory of two point charges under gravity

Tags: electrostatics, kinematics

Consider the following situation, with two identical point charges $q,m$ projected horizontally with velocity $v$. Originally the question asked to find the height of B when A strikes ground at a horizontal distance $l$ from point of projection. Although that can be solved for without knowing the trajectory of both the particles. **Is there any easy method to find the trajectories of both A and B?**

[image]

The main issue arises when we try to write the distance between any two particles at time $t$ because that itself is a function of its previous relative position. So how to go about resolving this? Thanks.